# jQuery Show/Hide nested divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, show, show-hide

I have awkward problem I cannot resolve.

I have a nested divs, which I want to show / hide when user clicks on a link. All divs at once.

I cannot assign ID's to my divs, so I will need to do it wiht classes.

```
<a href="#" id="showhide">Show more</a>

<div class="more">
<div class="more1">
<h2>Some title</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="more2">
<h2>Some title</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="more3">    
<h2>Some title</h2> 
<p>Some text</p>
</div>

</div>​
```

Here is the fiddle to my html structure. 
http://jsfiddle.net/56jdL/1/

Thanks!

Comment: Please check your jsfiddle now.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5uZ6X/

Comment: undefined: $('#' + id + ' .readmore').slideToggle('slow'); .. but the code is only for one div.. @Ravinder Singh- no update in my fiddle

Comment: @undefined: Working! how can I vote for ur answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use first hide the div, using `css`:

```
.more { display: none }
```

or jQuery:

```
$('.more').hide()
```

And then use `toggle` method:

```
$(function() {
   // $('.more').hide() 
   $('#showhide').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.more').toggle()
   })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J2YgE/

Comment: The problem is, that I did not expect that the upper answer would open all of the divs.. Let me explain.. I have lines (with custom fields) like a table.. And I want to open with only divs under one line, not all of the divs (for all the lines).. How would I do that with your code?

Comment: @MP Please provide a jsfiddle with your actual markup and I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#showhide").on('click', function(){
    $(".more").children("div").slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/56jdL/6/)**

### EDIT

To selectively toggle divs, give then a class by which they can be selected.

```
<div class="hideMe">
    ...
</div>
```

Then, the following jQuery will only act on those divs :

```
$("#showhide").on('click', function(){
    $(".more").children("div.hideMe").slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/56jdL/9/)**

### EDIT 2

Here's a version that will work on your more complete code :

```
$(".showhide").on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest(".vrsticaoglas").find(".more").children("div").slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5uZ6X/5/)**