# Show/hide/toggle display as a whole div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, hide

When i toggle the div showing below the buttons at the bottom of the div are displaying in a different/separated way (most part of the code are from another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797050/jquery-show-hide-nested-divs)).  How can it make it as a part of the wrapper div to slide out together?  Thanks.

css:

```
.more { display: none }
```

html:

```
<a href="#" id="showhide">Show more</a>

<div class="more" style="background-color:#f0f0f0;border:1px solid #d0d0d0;bottom:0px;display:none;height:30%;overflow:auto;padding:10px 10px 50px 10px;width:300px;position:fixed;right:0px;z-index:1;">
<div class="more1">
<h2>Risk Calculator</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="more2">
<h2>Some title</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
<p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="more3">    
<h2>Some title</h2>
<p>Some text</p>
</div>
        <div style="background-color:#ccc;border:1px solid #ccc;bottom:0px;height:30px;padding:10px;position:fixed;right:0px;text-align:right;width:300px;">
            <input type='button' value='button1' />
            <input type='button' value='button2' />
    </div>

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#showhide').click(function(){
   $('.more').toggle('slow')
})
```

See it in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/J2YgE/31/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the `more` class to the button div`. It seems to look pretty nice:

**Javascript:**

```
$('#showhide').click(function(){
   $('.more').toggle(400);
});
```

Here is the updated **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J2YgE/37/)**.

Comment: Even though this is not the answer i am looking for, it is a great work around.  Thank you.

Comment: I made it so they slide the direction you wanted them to and updated the fiddle. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, I was playing around with your suggestion and made it work just like your updated solution.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The position for the div containing the buttons was "fixed" meaning it was fixed to the window rather than its parent. Changing the position to "absolute" fixed the problem. Here is the snippet of your code that I changed.

The updated div style:

```
<div style="background-color:#ccc;border:1px solid #ccc;bottom:0px;height:30px;padding:10px;position:absolute;right:0px;text-align:right;width:300px;">
```

The updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/J2YgE/36/

Comment: Thanks for the answer; however, when you change fixed to absolute, the button banner no longer stay at the bottom of the div.  The button banner will be scrolled around while user scrolling the div.

Comment: I apologize for the oversight, I added a class to both the outer div and the button div "show-toggle" that I used for the jQuery toggle function instead. I also had to add "display:none" to the button div for it to work. Hope this helps, sorry for the late reply. http://jsfiddle.net/J2YgE/47/